# problem with testing POST method in postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman, composer-php

I am creating an api using composer, laravel and a mysql database in xampp.

The Get method works correctly, it returns me the message that is defined in the StudentController.php file

Contents of files in the project
StudentController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use App\models\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::all();
        if($students->count() > 0){
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 200,
                'students'=> $students
            ], 200);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 404,
                'message' => 'No records found'
            ], 404);
        }
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'course' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:191',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => $validator->messages()
            ], 422);
        }else{
            $student = Student::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'course' => $request->course,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
            ]);

            if($student){
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => "added student succesfully"
                ],200);
            }else{
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 500,
                    'message' => "something went wrong"
                ], 500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the web.php file

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Api\StudentController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function (Request $request){
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('students', [StudentController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('students', [StudentController::class, 'store']);
```

When testing method in POSTMAN, GET method returns correct values ​​in json format, however POST method returns values ​​in HTML form, I don't understand why, what do I need to correct?

[GET method postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTNV2.png)

[POST method postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2en71.png)

Feedback from html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Expired</title>

        <style>
            /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}code{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}code{font-family:Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Courier New,monospace}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-gray-400{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#cbd5e0;border-color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.border-r{border-right-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-xl{max-width:36rem}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-4{padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.uppercase{text-transform:uppercase}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.tracking-wider{letter-spacing:.05em}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@-webkit-keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}to{transform:rotate(1turn)}}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}to{transform:rotate(1turn)}}@-webkit-keyframes ping{0%{transform:scale(1);opacity:1}75%,to{transform:scale(2);opacity:0}}@keyframes ping{0%{transform:scale(1);opacity:1}75%,to{transform:scale(2);opacity:0}}@-webkit-keyframes pulse{0%,to{opacity:1}50%{opacity:.5}}@keyframes pulse{0%,to{opacity:1}50%{opacity:.5}}@-webkit-keyframes bounce{0%,to{transform:translateY(-25%);-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.8,0,1,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.8,0,1,1)}50%{transform:translateY(0);-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1)}}@keyframes bounce{0%,to{transform:translateY(-25%);-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.8,0,1,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.8,0,1,1)}50%{transform:translateY(0);-webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1);animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1)}}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}}
        </style>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center sm:pt-0">
            <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex items-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
                    <div class="px-4 text-lg text-gray-500 border-r border-gray-400 tracking-wider">
                        419                    </div>

                    <div class="ml-4 text-lg text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                        Page Expired                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: web.php protects requests with CSRF tokens.  Have you considered using the api.php routes file to prevent that from happening?  If you could post what HTML you are receiving, that would help.

Comment: Note, returning zero records should not (generally) be considered an error. The caller did not make a mistake client-side and the query succeeded server-side. You should return a 200 to indicate that the query succeeded, and return the appropriate result -- an empty set.

Comment: "POST method returns values ​​in HTML form" - what does that mean? Are you sure this problem is related to MySQL or Composer?

Comment: Check the Request header setting in Postman, it might be set to `text/html` instead  of `application/json`.

Comment: I added screenshots from Postman explaining what I meant when I wrote that the POST method returns html.

I also added what the html returns

Comment: As mentioned above, if you are writing an API, use the API route file. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files